# Accessing a variable through $options in the buildForm()

Tags: symfony

I want to pass a boolean to my `DogForm`

```
$dogForm = new DogForm(null, array("has_cats" => $this->getUser()->hasCats()));

$form = $this->createForm($dogForm, $dog);
```

But when doing in my `DogForm` :

```
if (!isset($options['has_cats'])) {
    throw new \Exception("Missing option has_cats, this option is mandatory");          
}
```

It always give me this error.

So i know that dogs aren't supposed to have cats but, **where my `has_cats` option went** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Options should be passed to the `createForm()` method, not to your `DogForm` constructor:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new DogForm(), $dog, array('has_cats' => $cats));
```

Mind, that you have to add "has_cats" to `getDefaultOptions()` as well

Comment: Thanks Kris. Just so other know if they read that, you'll have to add the "has_cats" in the getDefaultOptions() too in the CatForm.

Answer (score 11):

I'll add some best practice for those who'll read this, because at the time when I asked the question the OptionResolver wasn't as advanced as it is now:

Instead of checking the presence of the option `"has_cats"` in the form builder, it's better to do :

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'has_cats',
    ));

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'has_cats' => null,
    ));
}
```

This way if you omit to pass the `"has_cats"` options, it'll throw an error cause you marked the option as Required.

If you want more information, i'd suggest you to [read the option resolver documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/components/options_resolver.html)