# Symfony2 Self referencing many to many relation

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm new to symfony2 and forms are quite tough to get my mind around.

This topic has been covered before, but mainly to do with the relationship aspect. I'm having issues with the form and how to manage the saving of the relationships.
The scenario being A user has many friends who are users. So a self referencing many-to-many relationship.

I'm using FOSUser Bundle and have a friendship entity. Here is the YAML for creating the entities.

```
MH\FriendshipBundle\Entity\Friendship:
type: entity
table: mh_friendship
repositoryClass: MH\FriendshipBundle\Entity\FriendshipRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    requested_at:
        type: datetime
        gedmo:
            timestampable:
                on: create
    is_accepted:
        type: boolean
        nullable: true
    accepted_at:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
manyToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: MH\UserBundle\Entity\User
        inversedBy: user_friends
        joinColumn:
            name: user_id
            referencedColumnName: id
    friend:
        targetEntity: MH\UserBundle\Entity\User
        inversedBy: friend_users
        joinColumn:
            name: friend_id
            referencedColumnName: id
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist:   [ ]
    postPersist:  [ ]
    preUpdate:    [ ]
    postUpdate:   [ ]


MH\UserBundle\Entity\User:
type:  entity
table: mh_user
repositoryClass: MH\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    first_name:
        type: string
        length: 100
        nullable: true
    last_name:
        type: string
        length: 100
        nullable: true
    created_at:
        type: datetime
        gedmo:
            timestampable:
                on: create
    updated_at:
        type: datetime
        gedmo:
            timestampable:
                on: update
oneToMany:
    user_friends:
        targetEntity: MH\FriendshipBundle\Entity\Friendship
        mappedBy: user
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
    friend_users:
        targetEntity: MH\FriendshipBundle\Entity\Friendship
        mappedBy: friend
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
    friend_groups:
        targetEntity: MH\FriendshipBundle\Entity\FriendGroup
        mappedBy: owner
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist:   [ ]
    postPersist:  [ ]
    preUpdate:    [ ]
    postUpdate:   [ ]
```

Now i have a form that was create via the crud generator from the Friendship resource, and this is what i'm doing.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('friend', 'entity', array(
                            'class' => 'UserBundle:User',
                            'property' => 'fullName',
                            'expanded' => true,
                            'multiple' => true,
                            'required' => false,
                    ))
    ;

}
```

Which renders a list of checkboxes of users that i can select and save as "friends".

My problems are :

1. I get the following error when saving.

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to MH\FriendshipBundle\Entity\Friendship::setFriend() must be an instance of MH\UserBundle\Entity\User, instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given, called in /Users/mohammedhamad/Sites/sociabills/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 345 and defined in /Users/mohammedhamad/Sites/sociabills/src/MH/FriendshipBundle/Entity/Friendship.php on line 155, referer: http://sociabills.local/friends/new

Not sure how to make sure that the chosen are "friends" are passed to the setFriends method which expects a collection, and not the setUser method which expects a User object.

1. How to i get the form to list all other users, except for the logged in user. Don't want a person to befriend themselves.

Comment: I'm sure I know the answer to question 1 but it evades me now... thinking about it. As for question 2, you can use the `query_builder` option in the `entity` field type - you will probably need to manually pass a reference for the current user, or their id, into `buildForm`. You should be able to do this via the `$options` argument. I'll post an answer if I can coherently answer both questions..

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the doc

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="myFriends")
 **/
private $friendsWithMe;

/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
 * @JoinTable(name="friends",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
private $myFriends;

public function __construct() {
    $this->friendsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

// ...
```

}

The YML equivalent of the annotations would be (keep in mind I'm not used to yml for entity mapping and this is not tested)

```
   manyToMany:
     myFriends:
       targetEntity: User
       inversedBy: friendsWithMe
       joinTable:
         name: friends
         joinColumns:
           user_id:
             referencedColumnName: id
         inverseJoinColumns:
           friends_user_id:
             referencedColumnName: id
     friendsWithMe:
       targetEntity: User
       mappedBy: myFriends
```

Then you can implement `addMyFriend($friend)` method and `removeMyFriend($friend)` in your class

```
public function addMyFriend($friend){

 $this->myFriends[] = $friend;

}

public function removeMyFriend($friend)
{
    $this->myFriends->removeElement($friend);
}
```

Issue 2  was answered by @Darragh

Comment: I'm not sure i want to have a many-to-many relationship here. I need to be able to have extra fields (requested_at, is_accepted, accepted_at) to keep track of the relationship. I figured that the form type should be of data class User, and that the user class needs to be able to handle user objects being passed to it and set that info via the `addUserFriend` method. Only thing is that `addUserFriend` only accepts a `Friendship` entity. Would a data transformer be the right thing to use in this case to transform a User to a Frienship object?

Answer (score 1):

### Issue 1:

As I'm sure you noticed from the error, the first issue is occurring because `setFriend()` expects a single `User` entity, but is instead receiving an `ArrayCollection` of one or more `User` entities.

This was [discussed here in a blog post](http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1#collection-improvements) by Bernhard Schussek, the creator of the form component. I assume that you are using version >= 2.1? If so, the you need to add some additional methods:

```
public function addFriend(User $friend)
{
    $this->friend[] = $friend;
}
```

and:

```
public function removeFriend(User $friend)
{
    $this->friends->removeElement($friend);
}
```

My understanding is that these methods are called for every element in the `ArrayCollection`. I am looking at a similar example in one of my repos and this is what is implemented in one of my entities.

This is available in version >= 2.1.

### Issue 2:

To populate a form `entity` element with custom choices, you can use the `query_builder` option. A quick cut and paste example from my codebase here:

```
->add('client', 'entity', array(
    'class'         => 'HooluxDAPPUserBundle:Organisation',
    'property'      => 'name',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($builder) {
        if ($builder->getData()->hasAdvertiser()) {
            return $er->buildQueryClientsForAdvertiser(
                $builder->getData()->getAdvertiser()
            );
        }
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c');
    }
))
```

The `query_builder` option accepts an anon function/closure that receives a reference to the repository class for your Entity. You can call any custom method that returns a query builder object.

**Edit**

- [Documentation for `query_builder` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder)
- [Some answers on passing variables to the `buildForm()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702407/312962)

In your controller:

```
// pass current user's own id as an option 
$this->createForm(new FriendType(), $entity, array('user_id' => $this->getUser()));
```

In the `buildForm` method:

```
public function buildForm($builder, $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('friend', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'UserBundle:User',
            'property' => 'fullName',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
            // closure, include $options from parent scope with `use`
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                // current user's own id
                $userId = $options['user_id'];
                // call custom method on UserRepository class
                return $er->getUsersWhereIdIsNot($userId); // returns QueryBuilder object

            }
        ));
}
```

Then add a method that returns all users `WHERE id != :id` or whatever.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: started off with trying to use the query builder but for some reason i'm not able to pass a variable through to the form
`public function newAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $entity = new Friendship();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity, array('user'=>$user));

        return $this->render('MHFriendshipBundle:Friendship:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }`

Comment: i keep getting getting an undefined index when i'm passing over the user to the form. doesn't seem to be able to access it.

Comment: hi. when you use the `Controller::createForm()` method, the first argument is an instance of the form object, the second is the entity that the form represents - and the third (optional) argument is the array of options you can pass to the `buildForm()` method. In the example you posted, you are missing the entity (which I assume is a User entity) as argument #2

Comment: i figured it out. I basically added a protected $user to the form, and constructor to pass and set the user object. in the controller, when i instantiate the Form, i pass `$form = $this->createForm(new FriendshipType($user),` . Works like a charm. how i gotta figure out the whole saving of the collection.

Comment: Cool, best of luck with it!